# Can’t perform transactions on my gnosis safe as I misplaced my Two other wallet information

Tags: tokens, ethereum-wallet-dapp, gnosis-safe, multisignature, sendsignedtransaction

Been a while I used my gnosis safe and now I’m trying to claim my safe airdrop and discovered I can’t find my 2 other wallet information and I’ve got access to only one out of my 3 wallets. I can’t perform any transaction cause I need confirmation from atleast 2 of my wallets. I believe there should be a way out in situations like this

Comment: I don't know of a way to remedy such situation. As far as I know, in the scenario you described,  loosing two keys is like loosing your private keys. No way around it that I know of. Interested to see if there is any fail safe.